# Show that non-diagonal symmetric matrices must have at least two distinct eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra

"Food for thought" problem in university math class.  I know that symmetric matrices are diagonalizable and thus they are similar to a diagonal matrix which would have the same eigenvalues, but how would I show that these eigenvalues are necessarily distinct?

Comment: they are not.... consider the identity matrix

Comment: Which is diagonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By contradiction, assume $A$ is non-diagonal and symmetric, and has only one eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then, since $A$ can be diagonalized (it is symmetric): there exist $P, \Delta$ such that
$$
A = P^{-1}\Delta P
$$
But the assumption that $A$ only has one eigenvalue means that $\Delta=\lambda I$, and therefore 
$$
A = P^{-1}\lambda I P = \lambda P^{-1} I P = \lambda P^{-1} P = \lambda I
$$
and $A$ is diagonal, contradicting the hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

A nondiagonal matrix over the complex numbers that is diagonalizable always has at least two distinct complex eigenvalues. If not, then its diagonal form would have all entries on the main diagonal the same. However, a diagonal matrix with all diagonal entries the same commutes with every matrix and therefore cannot be similar to a nondiagonal matrix, which is a contradiction.

All eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix are real, so if a symmetric matrix is not diagonal it must have two distinct real eigenvalues.